# How do I format a number as decimal to store it in mysql?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I want to store a price for an item in decimal in MySQL.

How would I have to format the price in order to store in in the db?

Comment: What client language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do any formatting to store the data.

You can set the column type to `decimal` and do the formatting only when you display the value in the client, not when you store it.

Answer (score 2):

```
number_format($number, 2, ".", "");
```

Or if you want the commas in it, you can use this one:

```
number_format($number, 2, ".", ",");
```

Check out [`number_format()`](http://us.php.net/number_format) at PHP.net

Answer (score 2):

Mark Byers is correct; you shouldn't need to modify the data before sending it to mysql.

#### to update your mysql column:

`alter table foo change price price decimal(10,2) not null default 0`

If your `price` column is currently an `int`, you will not lose data with this query.

For example, a value of `10` will be updated to `10.00`, or a value of `5125` will be updated to `5125.00`, etc.